# How to change Activity Type list in quick campaign wizard?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

Is there any way to change activity list in Quick Campaign wizard in CRM 2011? I want to add one more activity here.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great question but unfortunately this is not possible with custom activities. You are constrained by the default options that you can see in your screenshot.

Possible workarounds:

1. Do what we used to in CRM 4.0 and repurpose one of the native activities (e.g. rename "Fax" entity) and use that
2. Add a hidden custom attribute to native activity and then use a plugin to "convert" each record with the attribute set into an instance of your own custom activity. This still won't surface your custom activity within your quick campaign but it will at least assist the "bulk creation" side of things.

Comment: Thanx @Greg. I was expecting your answer :)